# how to compare 2 columns and put zero on those rows in second column if they do not have match with any of rows from first column?

Tags: text-processing, columns

I have a file looks like:

file1:

```
    id1 id6
    id5 id2
    id2 id3
    id6 id500
```

if we compare the inside of the second column with the first column, we can note that id6 and id2 exist in the second column as well as first column. But id3 and id500 exist in second column while do not in first column. I want to replace 0 for the latter as they did not appear in first column. so the output should be:

output:

```
id1 id6
id5 id2
id2 0
id6 0
```

any suggestion? I tried some commands in "join", but I did not get what I want.
note that my real data is huge and this is a small example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A two-pass solution - in the first pass store all values from field 1 into an array `a`, in the second pass print each line, with the second field being set to 0 if it is not in the array `a`

```
awk 'first{a[$1]; next}; {print $1, !($2 in a)? 0: $2}' first=1 file first=0 file
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my  %hash;
my  @array;
my( $key, $value );

while( <ARGV> )
{
    chomp;
    @array = split '\t';    
    $hash{ $array[0] } = $array[1];
}

while(( $key, $value ) = each %hash )
{
    printf "$key\t%s\n",
        exists( $hash{ $value }) ? $value : "0";
}
```

Not sure what "huge" means though, whatever the size of your data, that's how much this uses.   Sorry if you were looking for POSIX command type solution, I've never answered on these forums before.

Comment: thanks. my file has 4000 rows. I tried to run your script. I got these errors:./test.perl: line 2: $'\r': command not found
./test.perl: line 3: use: command not found
./test.perl: line 3: $'\r': command not found
./test.perl: line 4: use: command not found
./test.perl: line 4: $'\r': command not found
./test.perl: line 5: $'\r': command not found

./test.perl: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `$key,'
'/test.perl: line 8: `my( $key, $value );
Do you know whay?

Comment: looks like my PC carriage returns got into the paste.  i tried to paste it without carriage returns, but i have no way of knowing it worked.  sorry :(

Comment: ???? I did not understand what your mean is

Comment: oh, silly me.  run it as a perl script not bash.

Comment: I ran it as perl script not bash. it did not work anyways

Comment: `#/bin/perl` is missing a `!`. This actually does work if you fix the shebang line; it doesn't maintain input ordering though.